# Lines of code per binary overtime in Golang

Tags: go, github, go-modules

In a single github repository containing multiple binaries code together. How can we find the total lines of codes per binary? Also, need to see the lines of codes per binary over a period of time.

For example in the below repository structure

```
cmd/service1
cmd/service2
pkg/service1
pkg/service2
```

Need to find the lines of code per service above?

Do we have any tools available to find this?

Comment: not sure exactly what you are asking but this might be helpful https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs

Comment: https://github.com/google/godepq/issues/30

Comment: What are you using this data for? A binary includes the runtime and all code referenced by your code, including stdlib and third-party packages. Is that what you're wanting to measure?

Comment: Yes mostly the vendored code and also the other dependencies the binary has. To figure out after which release the lines of code has increased by a big difference. And also to figure out which binary to be worked on first to split the repo from a single repo to a multi repo. Making changes here https://github.com/google/godepq/issues/30 to add a feature `--show-loc`